# My own program who work as "which" command in linux - dont work great

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

I would like to make my own program who will be work as `which` command in linux. Original `which` command works that (example for `pwd`):

`$ which pwd`

`/bin/pwd`

but my program works that:

`$ ./prog1 pwd`

`/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games pwd`

Can You correct my program? Source code:

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *systemPath, *path, *fileName;
    struct stat statStruct;
    if (argc < 2){
        printf( "Nothing to do\n");
    return -1;
    }
    if ((systemPath = getenv("PATH")) == NULL)
    {
        perror( "Not found PATH!\n ");
        return -1;
    }
        fileName = argv[1];
    printf("%s %s\n", systemPath, fileName);

    while ((path = strsep(&systemPath, ":")) != NULL)
    {
        if ((stat(fileName, &statStruct) == 0) && S_ISREG(statStruct.st_mode) && (statStruct.st_mode & S_IRUSR))
        {
            printf("%s\n", fileName);
            printf("%s\n", systemPath);
            printf("%s\n", path);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: it finds the binary file that would be executed, it can be launched without specifying the full path to 'which' binary, its name is a five letter word starting with 'w' and many other things can be said about this command. You need to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the candidate directory using `strsep`, storing it in `path`. But then you don't use this variable; the `stat` call just uses the base filename, which will therefore always be looked up in the current working directory.

You need to form the concatenation of `path`, a `/`, and the filename, and then `stat` that.

You will probably find `snprintf` useful.